# laravel 5 self relationship to json

Tags: mysql, json, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

How I make my query in laravel to a table with self relationship. And i need he return a query category and subcategory as  json format, for exemple:

```
['room':{
  bed room:1,
  kid room:2,
},
'living room ':{
   sitting-room:3
}][1]
```

Migration the tale:

```
 public function up() {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('subcategories_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('subcategories_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('categories');
//                    ->onDelete('cascade');

        });
    }
```

Comment: Please be more specific and also describe database table structure.

Comment: in the image have a structure database

Comment: so specifically you have one `category` table and one `sub_category` table and all you want is if you view particular category then its sub_category will be shown in that particular json ? correct me if I'm misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your proper solution would be

`Category Model`

```
class Cateogry extends Model {
    public function subCategory(){
        return $this->hasMany('\App\SubCategory');
    }
}
```

`SubCategory Model`

```
<?php
class SubCategory extends Model {
    public function Category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Category');
    }
}
```

In your controller

`SomeController`

```
<?php 

class SomeController extends Controller {
    public function index(){
        return Category::with('subCategory')->get()
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[
{
    name: 'Category1'
    created_at: '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    updated_at: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    subcategory: [
        {
            subcategory_name: 'subcategory1',
            created_at: '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            updated_at: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        },
        {
            subcategory_name: 'subcategory2',
            created_at: '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            updated_at: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        }
    ],
},
{
    name: 'Category1'
    created_at: '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    updated_at: '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    subcategory: [],
}
]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: We i do : return Category::with('subCategory')->get() i obtain  this error:
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `categories` where `categories`.`category_id`

Comment: I have to add 'id' in the:
     public function Category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Category','id');
    }